# HTML comment tag input validation in php

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form where users can fill comments in text boxes. Later I display the same fields on a page.
While testing I tried inserting HTML comment tag as a comment.
When I displayed the page it got messed up due to html comment tag.
I am doing input validation but cannot block all symbols.
Is there some security measure i have missed?

Even stackoverflow.com doesn't filter it. Try the html comment  tag in any comment.

Comment: It should be noted that allowing people to comment with unrestricted HTML is an XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `htmlentities($string)` or `htmlspecialchars($string)` to encode your output so it encodes your html tags instead of writing raw html to the page.

**htmlspecialchars()**

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

**htmlentities()**

```
<?php
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```